# Using a FTDI to USB adapter with a raspberry pi and a roomba

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, robotics, roomba

I'd like to control a Roomba 560 using its 8-pin mini din SCI port. I've seen other people do this [successfully](http://cfpm.org/~peter/RooPie.html) but I'm still unclear on how exactly to go about this. I was planning on using an USB to FTDI adapter, which is officially supported by the pi, and somehow wiring the pins to corresponding values. Would [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/70) cable work? And after getting it wired up, how would I control it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the webpage you referenced, the Roomba has a 5v interface. The cable you linked to is a 3.3v cable. They claim that it will work fine, and it appears to 5v tolerant to receive, but there's no guarantee that the Roomba will accept the 3.3v logic signals as valid. It depends on what transistor technology is used by the Roomba input and I'd give it 50/50 chance it would work with that cable (there's also the chance that it's on the edge and it works one day but not the next.)

However, you don't need to take the chance. This cable is a proper 5v FTDI and would cleanly interface between the Pi and the Roomba:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718

Just connect the Tx from the Roomba to the Rx of the Pi and vice-versa for the other Tx/Rx pair. Then make sure they share a ground through the pin as well. The remainder of the article describes how the author hijacked the 18 volt Roomba power supply to regulate it to a 5 volt for use by the Raspberry Pi.

Once you get it connected, start to read this manual:
http://www.irobot.com/images/consumer/hacker/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf

How you interface depends on what programming language you want to use. I recommend Python, and if so, install Pyserial (http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) on the Rasp Pi. Then you can use `import serial` and `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1')` to open a connection to the robot. (You might need something other than `/dev/ttyUSB1`) Then you can send individual bytes to the robot using `ser.write(chr(numeric_byte_to_send))` where you replace `numeric_byte_to_send` with whatever integer you want.

Comment: Nicely answered

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: Could be more specific about the wiring? I tried wiring the TXD/RXD to the correct places and wired ground, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: At this point, it will be very hard for me to figure out your bug remotely. System bring-up is one of the hardest tasks. Please submit a new question with a full schematic of what you've already done (photos would be awesome). As a starting point, you should test your Raspberry Pi serial port in loopback. Connect the TX and RX of the Pi's port to each other and see if you can hear the characters that you transmit.

Comment: The wiring was correct, the 5XX series uses a different baud rate than what is listed in the SCI spec.